# This closed question just got 10k views, we should fix it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

This looks like it's getting a bunch of views since it's probably a common problem for people with Optimus cards.

- [Nvidia driver cannot be installed with jockey for old hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126905/ubuntu-12-04-cant-use-nvidia-x-driver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 2 different issues on that question and all the relevant bug posts:

- This is a bug with jokey since it should not be offering the latest drivers to be used on that hardware;
- The hordes of people that arrive there and start giving random thoughts about how they fixed their random issue with their random Nvidia Optimus hardware;

Think this was closed as a valid off-topic issue since its a bug. We can of course re-open it and create some sort of warning for older cards, but for that we need to change the title since **the issue itself is very solvable but also specific for users that need to use the 170 version of the driver for older hardware.**

All other Nvidia Optimus issues are answered by the awesome Lekensteyn and his brilliant answers to users all over our site.

The thing is, the title is the only thing that got that question the 10k hits, if we change it to reflect the actual issue (installation of drivers via jokey for old hardware) I do not think it would get the same amount of hits.

We can:

1. Keep it closed and edit the title so the right people arrive here and read the bug report instructions;
2. Add the bug instructions to an answer, re-open the post. But we need to make the title more relevant to the issue;
3. Understand that this is only a random great title in the middle of all the posts we have about Nvidia and leave it like this.

I would like to do the 2nd, even if it means not getting as many hits as it has till now. Ideas, comments?

Comment: #2 sounds good. Indeed, I keep an eye on the gold badge for 10k questions because they're usually too-generic titles that suck in a bunch of views like "wireless ubuntu 12.04 broken"

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. What a coincidence, I opened this question because of the interesting title too :) Nice correction of the question!

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions:

- The bug report seems to have a good amount of information, perhaps make the bug comment a more solid answer.
- The posted answers look more like flailing with the same problems than solutions.
- Perhaps consider duping/merging it with? [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)
- Ask [Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn) what do do. :)

Comment: lol @ solution 4

Comment: Answer @ 3+4: the resulting error could be the result of multiple issues, Optimus being one of them. However, Bruno has nicely cleaned up the question + answers to match the actual intent of the OP. Closing it as another dupe for the Optimus question would not be very useful considering it's not related at all. But again, Bruno has nicely cleaned it up.